# MAMP: blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts' in /wp-includes/wp-db.php

Tags: mysql, mamp, flush, hosts, blocked

I have an issue with MAMP not connecting to databases hosted on another server. I recieve the following error:

Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1129): Host 'admins-MacBook-Pro-4.local' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts' in /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1538

things that are confusing me:
1) host admins-MacBook-Pro-4.local  -> I am not on a macbook pro, nor connecting to macbook pro. In my wp-config I am connecting to the server IP as the host.

Any one know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, had to login to the database on the server and type the following command in the SQL console.

```
FLUSH HOSTS
```